# Count occurrences of list of values in column using PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark DataFrame with a string column `text` and a separate list `word_list` and I need to count how many of the `word_list` values appear in each `text` row (can be counted more than once).

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
  [(1,'Hello my name is John'), 
   (2,'Yo go Bengals'), 
   (3,'this is a text')
  ]
  , ['id','text']
)

word_list = ['is', 'm', 'o', 'my']
```

The result would be:

```
| text                  | list_count   |
| Hello my name is John |       6      |
| Yo go Bengals         |       2      |
| this is a text        |       2      |
```

For text's first value, "is" occurs once, "m" occurs twice, "o" occurs twice, and "my" occurs once. In the second row, the only value from `word_list` that appears is "o" and it appears twice. In the third value for `text`, the only value from `word_list` that appears is "is" and it appears twice.

The result doesn't necessarily have to be PySpark-based either, it could be in Pandas if that's easier.

Comment: Are you sure your logic is consistent? `For text's first value..."m" occurs twice ... In the third value for [text], the only value from [word_list] that appears is "is" and it appears once.` In the same way `m` appears twice in the first row, does `is` not appear twice in the third row?

Comment: Yes you're correct... I'll edit that to make the logic right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a UDF as below

#### UDF

```
df = sql.createDataFrame(
  [(1,'Hello my name is John'), 
   (2,'Yo go Bengals'), 
   (3,'this is a text')
  ]
  , ['id','text']
)

word_list = ['is', 'm', 'o', 'my']

def count_values(inp,map_list=None):
    
    count = 0
    
    for pattern in map_list:
        if re.findall(pattern,inp):
            count += 1
    
    return count

count_values_udf = F.udf(partial(count_values,map_list=word_list),IntegerType())

df.select(
            count_values_udf(F.col('text')).alias('count_values')
         ).show()

+------------+
|count_values|
+------------+
|           4|
|           1|
|           1|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

To count number of occurrences of a substring in string column, you can split that column by the substring. The count corresponds to the size of resulting array minus 1.

So in your case, you can use `aggregate` function on the `word_list` array column and for each element, split the `text` column and get the `size - 1`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
    "word_list",
    F.array(*[F.lit(x) for x in word_list])
).withColumn(
    "list_count",
    F.expr("aggregate(word_list, 0, (acc, x) -> acc + size(split(text, x)) -1)")
).drop("word_list")

result.show(truncate=False)
#+---+---------------------+----------+
#|id |text                 |list_count|
#+---+---------------------+----------+
#|1  |Hello my name is John|6         |
#|2  |Yo go Bengals        |2         |
#|3  |this is a text       |2         |
#+---+---------------------+----------+
```